# Creating a new VIPER module from Wireframe using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, viper-architecture

I am trying to implement VIPER using SwiftUI. Firstly, I was returning a UIKit VC(`UIHostingController(rootView)`) from the Wireframe until I realized that in navigation, when presenter tells Wireframe to present a SwiftUI `View`, I can not pass a `UIViewController` trough a `NavigationLink`.

Having this issue, I tried to make Wireframe protocol to return a SwiftUI `View`, but it seems to be no possible

> Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has `Self` or associated type requirements

```
final class HomeWireFrame: HomeWireFrameProtocol {
//Error here returning a View
class func createHomeModule() -> View {

    var view = HomeView()
    //set up VIPER modules...
    .
    .

    return view
```

How can a I define a function that will return a SwiftUI `View`?

Answer (score 2):

Your Presenter class should have a variable of the protocol that the view implements.
So lets say that your `Presenter` who implements the `ModuleInput` and `ModuleOutput` Protocols has 2 variables on for the view of type `ViewInput Protocol` and one for the `router` of type `RouterInput Protocol`.

So you router Input classes and Router should be like this

```
 protocol RouterInput {
    func routeToAnotherView(from view: ViewInput)
}

class Router: RouterInput {
    func routeToAnotherView(from view: ViewInput){
        guard let viewInMyType = view as? MyType else {
            return
        }
        // Now you can go to your view
    }
}
```

And from presenter you will call the function with the parameter your `View` protocol outlet.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue returning a "HomeViewProtocol" instead a View... My HomeView conforms the HomeViewProtocol and of course, is a SwiftUI view.